# Alias route's name

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, routes

I need to have one path accessible through multiple names. In my `routes.rb` I did

```
get '/route' => 'controller#edit', :as => 'name_a'
get '/route' => 'controller#edit', :as => 'name_b'
```

This works nicely but loads the routes table for nothing. From my understanding of the documentation, `:as` defines a helper method when called.

So I went to my `ApplicationController` and added

```
alias_method :name_b, :name_a
```

and I removed the second line from `routes.rb`

but that fails with `Uncaught exception: undefined method name_a for class ApplicationController`

is there any proper way of having two names for a single path?

=================EDIT====================
Elaboration:

I use Devise gem to manage session, registration, locking, etc. of 2 kinds of users, let's call them `Admin` and `Guest`. The gem is very well put but it asks for definitive route names to behave properly.

In my case, as far as devise is concerned, only the registration process is different so I'm trying to build a structure which looks as follow:

```
app
  controllers
    users
        admin
            registration_controller.rb
        guest
            registration_controller.rb
        session_controller.rb
        password_controller.rb
        registration_controller.rb
```

the `Admin` and `Guest` controllers inherit from the above registration_controller which inherit's from Devise.

Now, to work properly, Devise needs for instance the names `guest_user_password` and `admin_user_password` to create or delete password retrievals. In my case, both are under the same path so I want both names to redirect to the same 'users/password' controller.

More important, and that's why I really wanted the alaising. Is that my views should not care whether it is dealing with `Admin` and `Guest` routes when redirecting to password retrieval controller. Both are users so I want to use `user_password` for both.

Hence my question. :)

Also note that as I wrote it, things works. I'm just trying to get the 'most elegant way' of writing it.

Comment: The :as => 'name_a' makes an alias you can use for the route, for instance name_a_path and name_b_path, its a routing mechanism not something that happens in the controller.

Comment: So that would mean no, there is no other way but to load the routing table. :( Thanks.

Comment: Why in the world would you need to reference the same path by different names?

Comment: Cause a gem asks for names I don't respect :)

Comment: Please elaborate. In either case you should be referencing a path with one name, not multiple.

Comment: "Cause a gem asks for names I don't respect" +1 I can agree with this.

Comment: so alias_method :name_b_path, :name_a_path doesn't work?

Comment: Konstantin: No it does not.

Comment: So you kept the two lines in your route?

Comment: What reason do you have for not loading the routing table? This seems like pre-optimization.

Comment: @Catfish, I have this same issue and the problem is that my route and controller are named differently than my model. The reason for this is because the remote database I'm connecting to doesn't follow rails standards. The model name matches the table name white the controller and route name follows rails standards. When I use the model in a `link_to` or similar, it gives the above error.

Answer (score 5):

How about putting the alias in your ApplicationController?

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base

alias_method :route_new, :route_old
helper_method :route_new
```

Remember that it's new name first, then old name.

The helper_method call is in order to use these in your views and not just controllers.

If you like, you can then place this in an included module called something like RouteAliases

Comment: This does not add any public route to the application.

Comment: @muichkine nor should it, why would you need a new route? But you know that you need to call it alias_method: :route_new_path, :route_old_path, right?

Comment: A new route would clarify the API for 3rd party integrators. But actually I found my solution with `  resources :goods, :controller => :items ,:type => 'Good'
  resources :services, :controller => :items  ,:type  => 'Service' `

Comment: I get a method not defined error with this as I start the server. Interestingly, if I comment out the code, start the server, then uncomment it and let rails autoload kick in it works.

Answer (score 1):

You can add something like this to your `routes.rb`:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do

  ...

  Rails.application.routes.named_routes.tap do |named_routes|
    named_routes['new_name'] = named_routes['real_name']
  end
end
```

This will create `new_name_path` and `new_name_url` helpers. I have tested this with Rails 5.0.6.